# Find 3 certain rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, limit

I want to find 3 certain rows in a MySQL request, lets say for example rows 5, 10 and 15

I know I could do 3 single request with

```
SELECT * FROM \`table\` WHERE \`value\` = '$value' LIMIT 4,1
SELECT * FROM \`table\` WHERE \`value\` = '$value' LIMIT 9,1
SELECT * FROM \`table\` WHERE \`value\` = '$value' LIMIT 14,1
```

But isn't there an easier way to do this and get everything into one query?

Comment: you can `union` them togehter or make sure the value = 'value' only shows 5, 10, 15 i dont know the context so this might not be an option

Comment: You might want to be careful, as MySQL doesn't guarantee the order of the data in the response without a `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `value` = '$value' LIMIT 4,1) as tmp1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `value` = '$value' LIMIT 9,1) as tmp2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `value` = '$value' LIMIT 14,1) as tmp3
```

Comment: Don't use UNION when you table could have duplicates

Comment: Don't use UNION ALL when you table could have duplicates  see this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bbb1/1   i ony get one result.

Comment: OP need 3 rows present at 5th 10th and 15th position, So lets say,if the 5th row is same as that of 10th and 15th. So resultset will have 3 rows exactly same, and I think this is what the OP needs

Answer (score 2):

Rows in MySQL are not ordered, that means, they can be returned in any order. So your proposed solution using `LIMIT` won't work forever. Instead add an `ID` attribute and query your date like below.

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE `value` = '$value'
  AND `ID` in (5, 10, 15)
```

Comment: OP need the 5th 10th and 15th record, how can this be possible for all the cases

Comment: If the table has a AUTO_INCREMENT ID column this is also possible if there are no gaps in the iD increments caused by deletes.

Answer (score 0):

It is rarely a good idea to reference rows by their position. Use the primary key. If you don't have a primary key - add one.

If you are **absolutely** certain that you **really** need to reference rows by their position you can use a UNION (as in Sashi Kant's answer) or you can give them sequential numbers and filter on them like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 
    @i=@i+1 as i,
    t.*
    FROM `table` t
    JOIN (SELECT @i:=0) #0 will make the row index 1-based, if you need 0-based you can change it to -1
    WHERE `value` = '$value'
    ORDER BY <something>
    LIMIT 15 #the max row num you want
) as t
WHERE t.i IN (5,10,15)
```

Comment: Side Note: If you using INNODB as storage engine you should ALWAYS add a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY in your table. i have wrote a post about on dba stackoverflow http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48072/why-does-mysql-ignore-the-index-even-on-force-for-this-order-by/48184#48184